# How to force the Word Automation Services Timer to run?

Tags: workflow, security, word-automation

I need to run the Word Automation Services immediately after adding a job. My code is running in a workflow.

Here is what I got so far :

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(site))
    {
        var job = new ConversionJob("Word Automation Services");
        job.UserToken = spSite.UserToken;
        job.Settings.UpdateFields = false;
        job.Settings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;
        job.AddFile(source, destination);
        job.Start();

        foreach (var service in spSite.WebApplication.Farm.Services)
        {
            if (service.TypeName == "Word Automation Services")
            {
                foreach (var jobDefinition in service.JobDefinitions)
                {
                    if (jobDefinition.Name == "Word Automation Services")
                    {
                        jobDefinition.RunNow();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But I got an access denied on the RunNow() method. Is there a way to call this method from a workflow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used reflection to force the Automation Services to execute immediately. Works fine in our environment :-)
http://devtopics.de/2013/11/18/making-sharepoint-2010-and-word-automation-services-convert-to-pdf-immediately-for-real/

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the schedule for the timer job to DateTime.Now, and update the job definition. Should execute it immediately that way.

Comment: Can you give a sample code for what you say ? I didn't found a way to translate what you said in code.

Answer (score 1):

jobDefinition.Schedule.NextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, it is more helpful if you can provide a bit more information than just a fragment of code. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't change anything.